# Issue using jquery on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Jquery does not work on the Internet explorer . However it runs on other webbrowsers . 
The code which I wrote is

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form)
            {
                $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data)
                {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php
    print "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> and your email is <b>".$_POST['email']."</b><br>";
?>
```

How do I run this code on INTERNET EXPLORER .Any help is very much appreciated on this

Comment: Have you got an error message from the JavaScript console? What version of IE are you using? We are developers as well not magicians :)

Comment: there is no error . When I click on submit button I again get the same page asking for name and email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove ',' after this line

```
email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
```

should be

```
 email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you."
```

In your messages block  it is like this

```
 messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",   // <<<< HERE REMOVE IT                
        },
```

you need to remove ',' (comma) in the last line no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `return false` to `submitHandler`.

Or you can convert your submit input to a button that doesn't submit the form using `<button>Submit</button>`.

Comment: I added return false but it would make no difference :(

Comment: Try with a button tag `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form)
        {
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data)
            {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No :( I still get the same page even after clicking on the submit button

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute your code at my end. Please add doctype at the top. I used the same and it worked while it was not working earlier.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

thanks

Comment: always use html5 doctype and never xhtml doctype!

Comment: which version of Internet Explorer are you using my friend ? It still does not work for me :(

Comment: I am using iE8. what did you exactly used at the top of the page.BTW comment your code and try to debug it step wise.